# Jigloo, Eclipse and Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Im fairly new at programming and was wondering if the Jigloo gui builder plugin would work with android app developement. I have Eclipse setup with the android sdk plugin configured, after seeing what Jigloo can do and that you can see the source code after creating the gui iI figured this would be a helpful tool to use.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me if it does work and how to configure it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Jigloo has nothing to do with Android, sorry.

Comment: Even in developing apps in eclipse? as creating java apps in eclipse is exactly the same as creating android apps. Jigloo is a GUI drag and drop plugin for eclipse.

Comment: @Jusbriggs: "CloudGarden's Jigloo GUI Builder is a plugin for the Eclipse Java IDE and WebSphere Studio, which allows you to build and manage both Swing and SWT GUI classes." Android does not use Swing or SWT. Hence, AFAIK, Jigloo has nothing to do with Android, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Android has its own GUI framework and doesn't use Swing/SWT (what Jigloo seems to be for), so I don't think you can use it to build Android GUIs. When you open a layout XML file in Eclipse and click the 'layout' tab, you can get a rough idea of what it will look like anyway.

You could check out [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) if you want a drag and drop GUI builder, although I'm not sure how regularly updated it is.

Comment: ive had a look at that. havent had chance to use it properly as im at work but it appears to do what I wanted jigloo to do. Thank you